# How to center figures at the top of the slide in LaTeX-Beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, horizontal-alignment

Using the 'Beamer'-documentclass, I have included several figures on different slides. I want all of these figures to be located at the same spot. Of course they differ in size, but I want them to start at the same top-line. For some reason the [t] - specification of the figure-environment doesn't seem to do the job. I am using both .tikz-figures and .png and .jpg - figures. Possibly the .png and .jpg - figures have some white background colour which is also filling the top of the figures ( I hope you know what I am talking about). But the difference shouldn't be that big.

```
\begin{frame}{Characteristics}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\input{pic/input_output}
\caption{characteristics.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Intermodulation}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{pic/intermodulation.jpg}
\caption{Intermodulation.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: try `\begin{frame}[t]{Characteristics}
\begin{figure} ...`

Comment: or better with `\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Characteristics} \begin{figure} ... `. please observe where is option`[t]`.